# Actionscript Double Buffer Audio playback by upscaling

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, stream, buffer, voip

I've been working on a way to stream mic data to a server, cycle back to clients, and play back in a packet by packet manner. So far, I have the client connectivity, intercommunication, voice sending, voice receiving, buffer storage, and a broken playback. The voice coming back plays at the proper speed without scratchy noise, but it's only ever playing a % of the voice buffer, recycling, and playing the new first %. I need the client to only play sound data it retreives once (asside from resampling for proper audio speeds) and then never again.

```
package Voip
{
    import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class SoundObj
    {
        private var ID:int;
        public var sound:Sound;
        public var buf:ByteArray;
            public var _vbuf:ByteArray;

        public var _numSamples:int;
        public var _phase:Number = 0;

        public var killtimer:Timer = null;
        public var _delaytimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
        public function SoundObj(id:int)
        {
            ID = id;
            buf = new ByteArray();
            _vbuf = new ByteArray();

            sound = new Sound();
            sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, SoundBuffer, false, 0, true);
            sound.play();
        }
        public function receive(bytes:ByteArray):void {
            var i:int = _vbuf.position;
            _vbuf.position = _vbuf.length;
            _vbuf.writeBytes(bytes);
            _vbuf.position = i;

            _numSamples = _vbuf.length/4;
            /*var i:int = buf.position;
            buf.position = buf.length; // write to end
            buf.writeBytes(bytes);
            buf.position = i; // return to origin

            if (_delaytimer == null) {
                _delaytimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                _delaytimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, finaldata);
                _delaytimer.start();
            }
            if (!_delaytimer.running) {
                // timer not running, dump buffer and reset.
                //var index:int = _vbuf.position;
                //_vbuf.position = _vbuf.length;
                //_vbuf.writeBytes(buf);
                _vbuf = buf;
                _vbuf.position = 0;
                buf = new ByteArray();
                //_vbuf.position = index;

                //sound.extract(_vbuf, int(_vbuf.length * 44.1));
                _phase = 0;
                _numSamples = _vbuf.length/4;

                // reset killtimer to silence timeout
                killtimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                killtimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, killtimerEvent);
                killtimer.start();
            }*/
        }
        public function killtimerEvent(event:TimerEvent):void {
            _delaytimer = null;
        }
        // send remaining data
        public function finaldata(event:TimerEvent):void {
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                trace("adding final content");
                //var _buf:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                //var index:int = int(_phase)*4;
                //if (index >= _vbuf.length)
                //  index = _vbuf.position;
                /*_buf.writeBytes(_vbuf, index, _vbuf.length-index);
                _buf.writeBytes(buf);
                buf = new ByteArray();*/

                //_vbuf = _buf;
                // add remaining buffer to playback
                var index:int = _vbuf.position;
                _vbuf.position = _vbuf.length;
                _vbuf.writeBytes(buf);
                _vbuf.position = index;
                // wipe buffer
                buf = new ByteArray();

                //sound.extract(_vbuf, int(_vbuf.length * 44.1));
                _phase = 0;
                //_numSamples = _vbuf.length/4;
                _numSamples = _vbuf.length/4;

                // reset killtimer to silence timeout
                killtimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                killtimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, killtimerEvent);
                killtimer.start();
            }
        }
        public function SoundBuffer(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
            //try {
            //trace("[SoundBuffer:"+ID+"]");
            //sound.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, SoundBuffer);

            // buffer 4KB of data
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 4096; i++)
            {
                var l:Number = 0;
                var r:Number = 0;
                if (_vbuf.length > int(_phase)*4) {
                    _vbuf.position = int(_phase)*4;
                    l = _vbuf.readFloat();
                    if (_vbuf.position < _vbuf.length)
                        r = _vbuf.readFloat();
                    else
                        r = l;
                }
                //if (_vbuf.position == _vbuf.length)
                    //_vbuf = new ByteArray();

                event.data.writeFloat(l);
                event.data.writeFloat(r);

                _phase += (16/44.1);
                if (_phase >= _numSamples) {
                    _phase -= _numSamples;
                }
            }
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

The initial idea was to create a SoundObj in my scene, use obj.receive(bytes) to add data to the buffer to be played back the next time the Sound player needed new data. I've been fiddling around trying to get it to work in one way or another since. The timers were designed to determine when to buffer more data, but never really worked as desired.

Proper double buffer, proper playback.

```
package VoipOnline
{
    import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

    public class SoundObj
    {
        public var ID:int;
        public var sound:Sound;
        internal var _readBuf:ByteArray;
        internal var _writeBuf:ByteArray;

        internal var n:Number;
        internal var _phase:Number;
        internal var _numSamples:int;

        internal var myTimer:Timer;
        internal var bytes:int;

        public function SoundObj(id:int)
        {
            ID = id;
            _readBuf = new ByteArray();
            _writeBuf = new ByteArray();

            bytes = 0;

            myTimer = new Timer(10000, 0);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
            myTimer.start();

            sound = new Sound();
            sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, SoundBuffer);
            sound.play();

        }

        public function receive(bytes:ByteArray):void 
        {
            var i:int = _writeBuf.position;
            _writeBuf.position = _writeBuf.length;
            _writeBuf.writeBytes(bytes);
            _writeBuf.position = i;

            this.bytes += bytes.length;
        }

        private function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void{
            trace((bytes/10) + " bytes per second.");
            bytes = 0;
        }

        public function SoundBuffer(event:SampleDataEvent):void 
        {
            //trace((_readBuf.length/8)+" in buffer, and "+(_writeBuf.length/8)+" waiting.");
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 4096; i++)
            {
                var l:Number = 0; // silence
                var r:Number = 0; // silence
                if (_readBuf.length > int(_phase)*8) {
                    _readBuf.position = int(_phase)*8;
                    l = _readBuf.readFloat();
                    if (_readBuf.position < _readBuf.length)
                        r = _readBuf.readFloat();
                    else {
                        r = l;
                        Buffer();
                    }
                } else {
                    Buffer();
                }
                event.data.writeFloat(l);
                event.data.writeFloat(r);

                _phase += 0.181;
            }
        }
        private function Buffer():void {
            // needs new data

            // snip 4096 bytes
            var buf:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var len:int = (_writeBuf.length >= 4096 ? 4096 : _writeBuf.length);
            buf.writeBytes(_writeBuf, 0, len);

            // remove snippet
            var tmp:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            tmp.writeBytes(_writeBuf, len, _writeBuf.length-len);
            _writeBuf = tmp;

            // plug in snippet
            _readBuf = buf;
            _writeBuf = new ByteArray();
            _readBuf.position = 0;
            _phase = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

These code snippets are based on this mic setup:

```
mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, this.micParse); // raw mic data stream handler
mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
mic.gain = 100;
mic.rate = 44;
mic.setSilenceLevel(voicelimit.value, 1);
```

After considerable testing, this seems to provide the best results so far. Little grainy, but it IS compressed and filterred. Some of the issues I'm having seem to be the fault of the server. I'm only receiving ~30% of the bytes I'm sending out. That being said, the code above works. You simply adjust the _phase increment to modify speed. (0.181 == 16/44/2) Credit will go where credit is due, even if his sample didn't quite solve the issues at hand, it was still a considerable step forward.

Comment: In the original, _numSamples was suppose to be the number of floats in the buffer, while _phase maintained a theoretical position in the upscaled buffer.

Comment: `mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;` could be the problem.. Just don't set a compression codec and have RAW feeding into the sampledata. I looked at your old code & you said sound was too short. Well 4kb of a raw PCM/WAV is gonna be very short. Its something like 10 meg per minute? You can try a maximum buffer of 65535 but still too many packets of bytes to send, eh? PCM is not for streaming.. (continued below)

Comment: (after double-checking..) So you come back to Speex which is correct for streaming over a network. You should use Netstream to play Speex audio bytes since it decodes that format (when inside FLV container). I've just done something similar for playing AAC files. I'll practice with Speex for a day or two & see if I can help..

Comment: After researching a little more on the sample I gave, _phase acts as a byte by byte "speed" modifier instead of going float by float (8 bytes per float). Slowing the playback to 0.35 (16/44) bytes per sound, you essentially extend the Speex codec to an appropriate state. I had to take out the _numSamples since it was designed for buffering mp3s, and was the cause of my initial problem. Still looking to clear up some of the bugs to get seamless streams. Right now there are still pauses. Additionally, 4096 loops equates to 32768 bytes of data.

Comment: You're correct.. I'm confusing byte amounts with sample amounts there!! Was also thinking maybe you involved sampleData just to store/sending but now I might get what you're doing. size compression (bytes) through speed? example: taking 10-sec sound, speed-up to 3s duration, now only 3s total bytes are sent but the receiving side can re-speed back to 10 seconds? Am I right? Problems is the receiving side only gets 3 secs or % of audio but its correct playback rate? Just "cropped" to the compression size at sending-time? I know it's a lot but we need clarity to help..

Comment: That's the general idea that I've come across when dealing with the speex codec. It's not losing a whole lot of sound quality when doing this method, as the byte-by-byte seems to be better than simply duplicating the same sounds back to back to back to slow it down. In the origional sample, it would only play a % based on numSamples, which is the number of floats in the supplied buffer, which would replay as it obtained more data (obviously not what I wanted). The new buffer system works wonders, but I'm having trouble balancing the choppiness and delays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared some sample data and fed it into your example and got only noise sound. I have simplified your class to only two buffers one for receiving samples and second one for providing them. Hope this will work:

```
package  {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class SoundObj
    {
        private var ID:int;
        public var sound:Sound;
        public var _readBuf:ByteArray;
        public var _writeBuf:ByteArray;

        public function SoundObj(id:int)
        {
            ID = id;
            _readBuf = new ByteArray();
            _writeBuf = new ByteArray();

            sound = new Sound();
            sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, SoundBuffer);
            sound.play();
        }

        public function receive(bytes:ByteArray):void
        {
            var i:int = _writeBuf.position;
            _writeBuf.position = _writeBuf.length;
            _writeBuf.writeBytes(bytes);
            _writeBuf.position = i;
            sound.play();
        }

        public function SoundBuffer(event:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
            {
                if (_readBuf.position < _readBuf.length)
                    event.data.writeFloat(_readBuf.readFloat());
                else
                {
                    if (_writeBuf.length >= 81920)
                    {
                        _readBuf = _writeBuf;
                        _writeBuf = new ByteArray();
                    }

                    if (_readBuf.position < _readBuf.length)
                        event.data.writeFloat(_readBuf.readFloat());
                    else
                    {
                        //event.data.writeFloat( 0 );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    // microphone sample parsing with rate change
    function micParse(event:SampleDataEvent):void 
    {
        var soundBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

        var i:uint = 0;
        var n:Number = event.data.bytesAvailable * 44 / mic.rate * 2; // *2 for stereo
        var f:Number = 0;
        while(event.data.bytesAvailable) 
        { 
            i++;
            var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat(); 
            for (; f <= i; f+= mic.rate / 2 / 44)
            {
                soundBytes.writeFloat(sample); 
            }
        }       
        snd.receive(soundBytes);
    }
```

Comment: This would probably have something to do with your default mic setup recording at a better ratio. Try setting it up in an onload function with these parameters (optimized for lower bandwidth)

    mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
    mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, this.onMicStatus);
    mic.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, this.onMicActivity);
    mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, this.micParse);
    mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
    mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
    mic.gain = 100;
    mic.rate = 44;
    mic.setSilenceLevel(voicelimit.value, 1);

Comment: just to clarify, I fed the `receive()` with sample data extracted from mp3 file

Comment: mp3 plays back at a different rate than mic. Try grabbing raw data from the mic SAMPLE_DATA and see if you notice my problem. Don't actually have to ping it off a server that way.

Comment: yes, now I see your problem. I had to resample microphone data to get things right. In my case mic had rate of 16 regardless of the fact I set it to 44. I am adjusting the code above but not quite sure it should work this way as there are still some noises.

Comment: MP3 is **compressed** audio (shorter codes for the full PCM values) so it's not supposed to sound good until decoded to PCM. If you send the bytes anyway the computer just obeys and you'll hear ##@@!!.. You can even play JPEGs as sound if you want. Or apply audio effects (echo, band EQ etc) to images (called Data Bending). Its just numbers. The noise is just "wrong" numbers..

Comment: of course it is however once you embed sound and use `extract()` you get the raw data. see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract()

Comment: I get you. It's because I use `fileReference` a lot for users to select files for audio effecting... fileReference is just the raw file bytes so I'm used to thinking of MP3s as the "noise" that I've almost forgotten that `sound.load` is also an automatic MP3-to-PCM decoder. `NetStream` is another decoder that handles AAC & Speex amongst others, formats which `Sound` functions like extract may not decode properly but NetStream does. Speex is a streamed format by Flash standards. So MIC --> SPEEX --> NETSTREAM = correct sound no "noise"

Comment: Came across a similar problem in another project (android touch to C# server). These types of projects are designed for streaming, which is better done in UDP. This project was in TCP, which buffers multiple packets before sending out, ensuring proper order, and lossless packets. TCP is better used for instant messaging, or file downloads for their purposes respectively.